# Get bootstrap buttons and image to align properly over divs

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get 3 buttons positioned centrally one under another on top of two div's that fill the page.

Currently, I can only get them to move horizontally to the left or the right, so far I have settled on the right positioning.

I have also tried putting the buttons in a group div to see if I can at least get them positioned centrally but I'm struggling to even get that to work.

Please see the second captured image, the lines represent roughly where I want to get the buttons to the position.

When you click the roll dice button, it puts a random dice image onto the page.

In the first image, I have put a line to show roughly where I want the dice to be positioned.

I have tried flex, changing the position type, display type, using inbuilt bootstrap positioning classes, but I just cannot seem to get it to work.

Any advice/help is greatly appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Dice Game</title>   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel ="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href ="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/all.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="wrapper">


<div class="modalButton">
    <button type="button" class="btn helpModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#helpModal">
        <i class="fas fa-question-circle fa-5x"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="helpModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="helpModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <h2 id = "modalHeader">Aim of the game</h2>
            <p><strong>Be the first player to reach a 100 global score.</strong></p>
            <ul style = "list-style-type:square;">
            <li>This game has two players playing in rounds.</li>
            <li>On each turn a player rolls a dice as many times as they wish. Each roll adds to their round score</li>
            <li>If the player rolls a 1, they lost their round score. It is then the other players turn.</li>
            <li>The player can choose to hold. Which means that their round score is added to their global score.</li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="text-center buttonGroup btn-group-lg">         
      <button type = "button" class = "btn"id = "newGame"><i class="fas fa-gamepad"></i> NEW GAME</button>
      <button type = "button" class = "btn" id ="rollDice"><i class="fas fa-redo"></i> ROLL DICE</button>
      <button type = "button" class = "btn" id ="hold"><i class="fas fa-hand-paper"></i> HOLD</button>
    </div> 


                <div class ="playerOne active">
                <h1 id ="name-0">PLAYER 1</h1>
                <h2 id ="roundScore-0">0</h2>
                <h3>CURRENT SCORE</h3>
                <h4  id ="score-0">0</h4>
                </div>


                <div class="playerTwo">
                <h1 id = "name-1">PLAYER 2</h1>
                <h2 id = "roundScore-1">0</h2>  
                <h3>CURRENT SCORE</h3>
                <h4 id = "score-1">0</h4>
                </div>
                <img src ="images/dice-1.png" alt="dice" id='dice'>
              </div>

<script src="index.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body, .wrapper {
font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}


.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}


/*buttons*/

.buttonGroup {
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
}

/*Player panels*/

.playerOne, .playerTwo {
height: 100%;
width: 50%;
margin: 0;
padding:0;
}

.playerOne {
float: left;
}

.playerTwo {
background-color: white;
float: right;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 4rem;
    padding-top: 30%;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 4rem;
    color: #EF2D56;
}

h3 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 5rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

h4 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #EF2D56;
    font-size: 2rem;

}

img {
    width: 3rem;
    height: 3rem;
    margin: auto;
    position: static;
}

/*Help Modal*/

.helpModal {
position: absolute;
}

#modalHeader {
    color: black;
}

.modal-body {
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
}
/*change content dependant on active player or the winner*/

.active {
    background-color: #0CCE6B;
}

.toggle {
    background-color: white;
}

#winner {
    position: absolute;
    width: 60rem;
    height:30rem;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

All of the content is inside of a "wrapper" div.

The image and the buttons are inside the wrapper but outside of the two "player" div's.

Thanks[image: Capture2]

[image: Capture]

Answer (score 0):

I have made three buttons in center, You can copy paste the whole code and see the changes

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Dice Game</title>   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
    .green{
      background-color: #0CCE6B;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    .white{
      background-color: white;
      height: 100vh;
    }

    .Player_heading{
      font-size: 3rem;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .Player_total_score{
      font-size: 2rem;
      color: red;
    }

    .current_heading{
      font-size: 1.5rem;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .current_score{
      font-size: 1rem;
      color: red;
    }
    .empty{
      height: 13vh;
    }

    .middle{
      z-index: -1;
    }

    .mt-cust{
      margin-top: 5rem;
    }
    .middle_btn{
      border: none;
      width: 200%;
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
      margin:15px;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-5 col-md-5 green ">
        <div>
            <button type="button" class="btn helpModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#helpModal">
                <i class="fa fa-question-circle fa-5x"></i>
            </button>    
        </div>
        <div class="mt-5 text-center">
          <h3 class="Player_heading">Player 1</h3>
          <h5 class="Player_total_score">0</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="mt-5 text-center">
          <h4 class="current_heading">Current Score</h4>
          <h6 class="current_score">0</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 col-md-2">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col green">
              <div class="mt-cust">
                  <button class="middle_btn">Test Btn</button>
              </div>
              <div>
                  <button class="middle_btn">Test Btn</button>
              </div>
              <div>
                  <button class="middle_btn">Test Btn</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col white middle">

            </div>        
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-5 col-md-5 white">
        <div class="empty">

        </div>
        <div class="mt-5 text-center">
          <h3 class="Player_heading">Player 1</h3>
          <h5 class="Player_total_score">0</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="mt-5 text-center">
          <h4 class="current_heading">Current Score</h4>
          <h6 class="current_score">0</h6>
        </div>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
<script src="index.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope it'll be helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

This is it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Dice Game</title>   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel ="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href ="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/all.css">
<style>
html, body, .wrapper {
font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}


.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}


/*buttons*/

.buttonGroup {
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
}

/*Player panels*/

.playerOne, .playerTwo {
height: 100%;
width: 50%;
margin: 0;
padding:0;
}

.playerOne {
float: left;
}

.playerTwo {
background-color: white;
float: right;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 4rem;
    padding-top: 30%;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 4rem;
    color: #EF2D56;
}

h3 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 5rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

h4 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #EF2D56;
    font-size: 2rem;

}

img {
    width: 3rem;
    height: 3rem;
    margin: auto;
    position: static;
}

/*Help Modal*/

.helpModal {
position: absolute;
}

#modalHeader {
    color: black;
}

.modal-body {
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
}
/*change content dependant on active player or the winner*/

.active {
    background-color: #0CCE6B;
}

.toggle {
    background-color: white;
}

#winner {
    position: absolute;
    width: 60rem;
    height:30rem;
    visibility: hidden;
}</style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="wrapper">


<div class="modalButton">
    <button type="button" class="btn helpModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#helpModal">
        <i class="fas fa-question-circle fa-5x"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="helpModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="helpModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <h2 id = "modalHeader">Aim of the game</h2>
            <p><strong>Be the first player to reach a 100 global score.</strong></p>
            <ul style = "list-style-type:square;">
            <li>This game has two players playing in rounds.</li>
            <li>On each turn a player rolls a dice as many times as they wish. Each roll adds to their round score</li>
            <li>If the player rolls a 1, they lost their round score. It is then the other players turn.</li>
            <li>The player can choose to hold. Which means that their round score is added to their global score.</li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="text-center buttonGroup btn-group-lg">         
      <button type = "button" class = "btn"id = "newGame"><i class="fas fa-gamepad"></i> <pre>NEW GAME</pre></button>
      <button type = "button" class = "btn" id ="rollDice"><i class="fas fa-redo"></i> <pre>ROLL DICE</pre></button>
      <button type = "button" class = "btn" id ="hold"><i class="fas fa-hand-paper"></i> <pre>HOLD</pre></button>
    </div> 


                <div class ="playerOne active">
                <h1 id ="name-0">PLAYER 1</h1>
                <h2 id ="roundScore-0">0</h2>
                <h3>CURRENT SCORE</h3>
                <h4  id ="score-0">0</h4>
                </div>


                <div class="playerTwo">
                <h1 id = "name-1">PLAYER 2</h1>
                <h2 id = "roundScore-1">0</h2>  
                <h3>CURRENT SCORE</h3>
                <h4 id = "score-1">0</h4>
                </div>
                <img src ="images/dice-1.png" alt="dice" id='dice'>
              </div>

<script src="index.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
var d1 = document.getElementById('newGame');
d1.style.position = "absolute";
d1.style.left = -675+'px';
d1.style.top = 200+'px';

var d2 = document.getElementById('rollDice');
 d2.style.position = "absolute";
 d2.style.left =-675+'px';
 d2.style.top = 300+'px';

 var d3 = document.getElementById('hold');
 d3.style.position = "absolute";
 d3.style.left = -675+'px';
 d3.style.top = 400+'px';

</script></body>
</html>
```

Thanks!!!!